# Microsoft Visual C++ 2003, 2005-- Are They .Net or Unmanaged?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

It's kind of confusing when it comes to Microsoft Visual C++.

How to tell whether a Microsoft Visual C++ project is a .Net project, or a native C++ project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually if the switch /clr:xxx is present it is managed code

I say usually since if you apply /clr:xxx on unmanaged C++ code you get a warning

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008 all support both Managed and Native applications.

In 2008, go to properties on the project, look in the "General" section, and look at the "Common Language Runtime Support" item.

In 2003, it's called "Use Managed Extensions", I think.

Comment: I think they're asking if there is a way to tell if a VC++ project is .NET or natively compiled.